# Objection.js Syntax for INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: node.js, postgresql, objection.js, knex.js

The datastore is postgres. Can someone help in translating this to an Objection.js statement? It's easy to do this with two roundtrips, but ideally this would happen in one.

```
INSERT INTO reports (
    id,
    created_by,
    desc,
    dataset
)
SELECT 
    '8971e660-7777-4d64-8cc3-171512063fff',
    123,
    'clone!',
    r.dataset,
FROM reports r
WHERE r.id = '7771e660-9d7d-4d64-8cc3-17151206354f';
```